# Rails: Proper way for MySQL query to search multiple attributes

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, heroku

I know very little about SQL. My app is running Rails 3.0.9. I have a search feature in my app which allows a user to search for photos, but right now the query only checks `photo.name`:

```
where("photos.name LIKE ?", "%#{search}%")
```

I would like it to ALSO check the `photo.description` for a match. I tried the following:

```
where("photos.name OR photo.description LIKE ?", "%#{search}%")
```

That seemed to actually work in development (I use SQLite in development), but once on Heroku, this code failed. What is the proper way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: the SQL syntax would be `photos.name LIKE ? OR photo.description LIKE ?` if you just have `WHERE photos.name` mysql will convert `photos.name` into a boolean and only output tuples that evaluate to true. if you add a second `?` in your where-call, you may need to add a 3rd argument, possibly `"%#{search}%"` again, but i don't know how things roll in rails.

Comment: Thanks man, this seems to be working. (Not sure what I didn't think of this!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
where("photos.name LIKE ? OR photo.description LIKE ?", "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%")
```

Answer (score 0):

> but once on Heroku

Heroku uses PostGres not mySQL - Are you using a mySQL addon to provide mySQL to your application? The syntax may/will be different between different DB's - I encourage you to develop against the DB you will be going into production using.